# JQuery Select Attribute Range

Tags: javascript, jquery

Kind of like this:

```
$("[day=5]").html('hi');
```

But for a range like this:

```
$("[day>5]").html('hi');
```

Because I want that to work so bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the function overload of [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), like this:

```
$("[day]").filter(function() {
  return +$(this).attr("day") > 5;
})
```

Comment: You can combine that with `$("[day]")` selector.